# Dual Boot Problem in Installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 8.1 Pro in Legacy Mode

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I have a HP Probook 440 G2 Moded Version with Specification, 8gb ram, I5 Processor, 500 Hard Disk and its 64 Bit.

```
When i first got it it was dual booted with Windows 8.1 pro and Ubuntu 14.02 LTS in Legacy Mode. Many times the Lapy went slow and it got formated but still dual boot worked. Later on i decided to use UEFI instead of Legacy and booted my Lapy with Windows 8.1 Pro in UEFI Mode and whwn i tried to have a dual boot with ubuntu in UEFI there were lots of problem and i was not able to use linux and i was forced to boot my laptop back to Legacy, so i formated it with Windows in Legacy, and now the problem comes that when i install ubuntu from usb alongside windows 8.1 Pro like before i get a problem.

Before Ubuntu automatically used to detect windows and i used to get a option of "Dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8" but now a days it is unable to detect Windows and i don't get that option and askes to install ubuntu by erasing the disk.

Please someone help me urgently.
```

Thanking You.

AYUSH AGARWAL.